# ¿ Como enviar correo con Codeigniter usando Libreria email?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, phpmailer, email

Estoy empezando a programar por lo tanto estoy haciendo una pagina web pero el correo de consulta no funciona, no envía la descripción.

Podrían ver mi codificación que esta con `Codeigniter` y explicarme un poco en que estoy mal o porque no funciona o es otro tipo de problema.

El proveedor del hosting se llama HOSTPER PERU.

Este es mi código:

```
//codigo del controllador 
public function  sendEmail(){
  $config = array(
  'protocol' => 'smtp',
  'smtp_host' => 'smtp.googlemail.com',
  'smtp_user' => 'correoempresa@hotmail.com', //El correo de la empresa
   'smtp_pass' => '', // Su Password de Gmail aqui
  'smtp_port' => '465',
  'smtp_crypto' => 'ssl',
  'mailtype' => 'html',
  'wordwrap' => TRUE,
  'charset' => 'utf-8'
  );

  $this->load->library('email', $config);
  $nombres = $this->input->post('nombres');
  $email = $this->input->post('email'); 
  $mensaje = $this->input->post('mensaje');  
  $telefono = $this->input->post("telefono"); 
  $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
  $this->email->from($email, $nombres);
  $this->email->subject("Nueva Consulta !");
  $this->email->message('<p>'.$mensaje.,'<strong>'.$telefono.'</strong>''</p>');
  $this->email->to('correoempresa@hotmail.com');
  if($this->email->send(FALSE)){ 
    echo json_encode("success");
  }else {
    echo json_encode("error");
  }
}
```

Comment: Tienes una coma extra en esta linea: `$this->email->message('<p>'.$mensaje.,'<strong>'.$telefono.'</strong>''</p>');`

Answer (score 0):

He utilizado esta librería y me funciona perfectamente solo adaptarla a tus necesidades.

```
$this->load->library("email");

$configGmail = array(
    'protocol'  => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'correo',
    'smtp_pass' => 'password',
    'mailtype'  => 'html',
    'charset'   => 'utf-8',
    'newline'   => "\r\n"
);

$this->email->initialize($configGmail);

$this->email->from('correo_quien_envia');
$this->email->bcc($email_destinatario);

ob_start();
include(APPPATH.'libraries/info.php');
$HTML = ob_get_clean();

$this->email->subject('Mensaje');
$this->email->message($HTML);
$this->email->send();
```

Comment: En la configuración **$configGmail** es importante que se ponga la contraseña del correo  ? por que en un correo gmail me funciona perfectamente pero el de la empresa es un hotmail.

Comment: Si tienes que configurarlo.

Comment: que pasaría si se cambia la contraseña del correo.

Comment: Tendría que cambiarse también